# insert hex data at specific offset

Tags: c#, hex, offset

I need to be able to insert audio data into existing ac3 files.  AC3 files are pretty simple and can be appended to each other without stripping headers or anything.  The problem I have is that if you want to add/overwrite/erase a chunk of an ac3 file, you have to do it in 32ms increments, and each 32ms is equal to 1536 bytes of data.  So when I insert a data chunk (which must be 1536 bytes, as I just said), I need to find the nearest offset that is divisible by 1536 (like 0, 1536 (0x600), 3072 (0xC00), etc).  Let's say I can figure that out.  I've [read about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231234/replacing-a-specific-hex-offset-in-c-sharp) changing a particular character at a specific offset, but I need to INSERT (not overwrite) that entire 1536-byte data chunk.  How would I do that in C#, given the starting offset and the 1536-byte data chunk?

Edit: The data chunk I want to insert is basically just 32ms of silence, and I have the hex, ASCII and ANSI text translations of it.  Of course, I may want to insert this chunk multiple times to get 128ms of silence instead of just 32, for example.

Comment: You cannot in general *insert* anything in a file by simply calling a command. You can implement this by first reading the data block (of the size that you want to insert) at the specified offset, seek back to the original position and then overwriting it by your own data block. Then you can read the data into a temporary block buffer and continue first reading, seeking and writing the rest of the file. This is probably the most efficient way of doing this, using a [memory mapped file stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267540.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] filbyte=File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\abc.ac3");
byte[] tobeinserted=;//allocate in your way using encoding whatever

byte[] total=new byte[filebyte.Length+tobeinserted.Length];

for(int i=0;int j=0;i<total.Length;)
{
   if(i==1536*pos)//make pos your choice
   { 
     while(j<tobeinserted.Length) 
       total[i++]=tobeinserted[j++];
   }
   else{total[i++]=filbyte[i-j];}
}

File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\abc.ac3",total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper method that will do what you need:

```
public static void Insert(string filepath, int insertOffset, Stream dataToInsert)
{
    var newFilePath = filepath + ".tmp";
    using (var source = File.OpenRead(filepath))
    using (var destination = File.OpenWrite(newFilePath))
    {
        CopyTo(source, destination, insertOffset);// first copy the data before insert
        dataToInsert.CopyTo(destination);// write data that needs to be inserted:
        CopyTo(source, destination, (int)(source.Length - insertOffset)); // copy remaining data
    }

    // delete old file and rename new one:
    File.Delete(filepath);
    File.Move(newFilePath, filepath);
}

private static void CopyTo(Stream source, Stream destination, int count)
{
    const int bufferSize = 32 * 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    var remaining = count;
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        var toCopy = remaining > bufferSize ? bufferSize : remaining;
        var actualRead = source.Read(buffer, 0, toCopy);

        destination.Write(buffer, 0, actualRead);
        remaining -= actualRead;
    }
}
```

And here is an NUnit test with example usage:

```
[Test]
public void TestInsert()
{
    var originalString = "some original text";
    var insertString = "_ INSERTED TEXT _";
    var insertOffset = 8;

    var file = @"c:\someTextFile.txt";

    if (File.Exists(file))
        File.Delete(file);

    using (var originalData = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(originalString)))
    using (var f = File.OpenWrite(file))
        originalData.CopyTo(f);

    using (var dataToInsert = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(insertString)))
        Insert(file, insertOffset, dataToInsert);

    var expectedText = originalString.Insert(insertOffset, insertString);

    var actualText = File.ReadAllText(file);
    Assert.That(actualText, Is.EqualTo(expectedText));
}
```

Be aware that I have removed some checks for code clarity - do not forget to check for null, file access permissions and file size. For example `insertOffset` can be bigger than file length - this condition is not checked here.